# C# Progress bar - error on BackgroundWorker's progress changed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, progress-bar, outofrangeexception

**What it does**:

Reads the values in a datagridview into the database ACTB row by row.

---

To be clear, this exact same code works on my other program without issue, I don't know why my current program is throwing errors every time I run the background worker.

I receive the error: 2500 is not a valid value for 'Value' (progressbar.value) 'Value' must be between minimum and maximum.

Here is my code.

**Do Work**:

```
    int MaxSchema = 0;
    private void Transfer_Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Con))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    MaxSchema = DGVExcel.Rows.Count;
                    for (int s = 0; s < DGVExcel.Rows.Count; s++) 
                    {
                    Transfer_Worker.ReportProgress(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Import error: " + ex);
        }
        Transfer_Worker.ReportProgress(100);
    }
```

**Progress Changed**:

```
 private void Transfer_Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbar.Value = (e.ProgressPercentage * 100) / MaxSchema;
    }
```

Now, commenting out my code in progress changed seems to make the process run as expected, even the progressbar's values get updated. I don't know why this is, if the same block of code works elsewhere.

I have not modified the progressbar in anyway, so it should still have default properties.

Could it be that it is because I report progress on my dowork function? Correct me if this is something I need to change. First of all, I assume that I am not permitted to update the UI with the Work method of Background workers, so it should throw an error but it doesn't.

**EDIT**: It appears that the error is caused by the line

```
  Transfer_Worker.ReportProgress(100);
```

Changing the value from 100 (Presumed maximum) to MaxSchema (Actual value of rows.Count), the progress bar was able to correctly determine the end point.

Comment: in `(e.ProgressPercentage * 100) / MaxSchema`, `ProgressPercentage` will e as large as 100 and MaxSchema = 3, so the value will be very large, but the maxvalue is 100, so exceeded.

Comment: _"I have no idea where this number is coming from because the sheet data I am trying to insert only contains a maximum of 3 rows plus a header"_ -- did you actually _verify_ that assumption by debugging the code and checking to see what `DGVExcel.Rows.Count` returns? I'll also point out that `(100 * 100) / 3` (where `3` is what you _claim_ `MaxSchema` will be set to) is `3333`, well above the default `MaxValue` for a `ProgressBar`. In any case, until you fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say for sure what your bug is.

Comment: (Just to be clear, `(100 * 100) / MaxSchema` comes from your program statement `Transfer_Worker.ReportProgress(100);` at the end of the `DoWork` event handler.)

Comment: Just add some logging to the ProgressChanged method to check `e.ProgressPercentage` and `MaxSchema` values

Comment: @PeterDuniho, `(100*100) / (3)` does not explain the number 25500.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Here's what I found: MaxSchema = a value of 4, including the headers. and then progresses like so for each row: .0, .25, .50, .75, .2500. This is with the ReportProgress(100) disabled. (same as if it were enabled)

Comment: @KernelMode: yeah, I know that. I can do math (I even showed my work in my previous comment). My point is that even if the OP wasn't getting the 25500 value, they'd still be getting an invalid value from values _they_ hard-coded into the code. Bottom line: called to the `ProgressChanged` event handler don't just come out of the blue; the OP is calling it somewhere with a value that leads to `25500` being assigned to `Value` (assuming everything they report in the question is correct...without a [mcve], we have no way to confirm that).

Comment: _"progresses like so for each row: .0, .25, .50, .75, .2500"_ -- I don't know what that means. You're using `int` for all the operands in your calculation, so there's no way you get decimal values like those. And there's no numerical difference between `.25` and `.2500`. Please be more specific, so it's clear what you're talking about.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I apologize for being slightly incoherent, you were absolutely correct about the ReportProgress(100) being the issue here I've reviewed my code and made the necessary changes. If you make it as an answer I will accept it. My followup question is why didn't this same code throw an error for my other program? The structure is exactly the same (I copied it) even with the ReportProgress(100) in place, and yet it threw no errors. The only difference that I note is that I am dealing with 2700000 more rows, but I can hardly believe that to be a problem.

Comment: I am glad you were able to fix the problem. I don't feel it would be appropriate for me to post an answer, as frankly I still don't know how `(100 * 100) / 3` leads to `25500`. If you feel you can clean up the question, so it includes a good [mcve], and you can post an answer yourself (which you can self-accept) that fully and logically explains the error and how to fix it, you should consider doing that.

Comment: (Dealing with more rows would prevent the problem, because you're dividing by `MaxSchema`. With enough rows, the result of the calculation is small, and with `2700000` rows, the result is `0`, well below the default maximum value :). To get correct results, you should probably be passing `MaxSchema` instead of `100` at that line.)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a default value (100) to the TransferWorker's `ReportProgress` property caused the progress bar value to bloat past 100% when the value of `MaxSchema` was much smaller than that. (100*100)/4 = the reported value of 2500.

Change the value of report progress to match the actual row count. In this case, the correct line would be:

```
 TransferWorker.ReportProgress(MaxSchema);
```

Regarding the second issue of it working in the past with a significantly larger collection of rows, as stated by Peter:

```
 Dealing with more rows would prevent the problem, because you're dividing by MaxSchema. With enough rows, the result of the calculation is small, and with 2700000 rows, the result is 0, well below the default maximum value.`"
```